# If a functions return an int, can an int be assigned to it?

Tags: c++, function, rvalue

If a function returns an int, can it be assigned by an int value? I don't see it makes too much sense to assign a value to a function.

```
int f() {}

f() = 1;
```

I noticed that, if the function returns a reference to an int, it is ok. Is it restricted only to int? how about other types? or any other rules?

```
int& f() {}

f() = 1;
```

Comment: what would be the point to assign a value to a function ? Why not use a variable instead ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The first function returns an integer by-value, which is an **r-value**. You can't assign to an r-value in general. The second f() returns a reference to an integer, which is a l-value - so you can assign to it.

```
int a = 4, b = 5;

int& f() {return a;}

...
f() = 6;
// a is 6 now
```

Note: you don't assign a value to the function, you just assign to its return value. 
Be careful with the following:

```
int& f() { int a = 4; return a; }
```

You're returning a reference to a temporary, which is no longer valid after the function returns. Accessing the reference invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: could you explain why return by-value is a r-value?

Comment: The return value of a function isn't a proper C++ variable, such as `int i;`. It is just a temporary value. It doesn't represent a memory location.

Comment: @skydoor, it can be summarized by *"you can only assign to objects"* . In your call, the function returns a value that doesn't correspond to an object: The integer represents *just* an abstract value. If you had, for example, returned a `std::string`, the value returned (which is actually an r-value) will correspond to a string object, and you *could* assign to it. The same is true for a `int&` return value. In that case, the "value" returned (which is an l-value) corresponds to an int *object*, and you can assign to it. An object is necessary, because an assignment modifies a stored state.

Answer (score 2):

- [What are Lvalues and Rvalues?](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/5696) by Danny Kalev
- [Lvalues and Rvalues](http://www.embedded.com/story/OEG20010518S0071) by Dan Saks
- [Lvalues and Rvalues](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/227) by Mikael Kilpeläinen

Answer (score 1):

It's not limit to int only, but for the primitive types there no point in doing it. It's useful when you have your classes

Comment: Are you saying there is no point in returning a reference to a primitive type? So things like `operator[]` of `vector<int>` are pointless?

Comment: There is a lot of point in doing it (if by 'it' you mean returning a reference) - if you have  a std::vector<int> then the functions that access things in the vector return int references.

Comment: In the context of his example

Answer (score 0):

If a function returns an object by value, then assignment is possible, even though the function call is an rvalue. For example:

```
std::string("hello") = "world";
```

This creates a temporary string object, mutates it, and then immediately destroys it. A more practical example is:

```
some_function(++list.begin());
```

You could not write `list.begin() + 1`, because addition is not possible on list iterators, but increment is fine. This example does not involve assignment, but assignment is just a special case of the more general rule "member functions can be called on rvalues".

Comment: It's a common case? Can you give me an example?

Comment: While i understand it's just an example, notice that `++list.begin()` is not required to work. The operator can be implemented as a free function which accepts a non-const reference and will fail to bind to the iterator temporary.

Comment: Thanks, I can never remember which operators have to member functions and which can be free functions.