# why error lvalue required as left operand does not exhibit for strings?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator, rvalue

In below code snippet, why line `2 + 3 = 5` statement gives error but next statement of assigning to string concatenation compiles successfully?

```
#include <string>

int main() {                                                                                                                                                  
   2 + 3 = 5;   //  Error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment                                                                                                                                             
   std::string("2") + std::string("3") = std::string("5");  // Compiles successfully. why?                                                                                                 
   return 0;                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

My understanding is that left hand side of the expression `std::string("2") + std::string("3") = std::string("5")` will produce temporary which is `rvalue`. That means I am assigning to `rvalue` - just like `2 + 3 = 5`. So it should also give `lvalue required as left operand of assignment` error. But it does not.

Comment: Simplification `std::string("3") = std::string("5");` still compiles

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ function returns a rvalue, but that can be assigned a new value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824750/c-function-returns-a-rvalue-but-that-can-be-assigned-a-new-value)

Comment: Just checked most of the standard containers and non of them have the the rvalue version of `operator=` deleted eg `basic_string& basic_string::operator=( CharT ch ) && = delete;` is not done for any of the containers.  So I guess it is a conscious decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Explanation

For class types, assignment is implemented by copy and move assignment operators.  `std::string` is a class, so

```
std::string("2") + std::string("3") = std::string("5")
```

is just syntactic sugar for

```
(std::string("2") + std::string("3")).operator=(std::string("5"))
```

`operator=` is a member function.  Usually, a member function can be called on both lvalues and rvalues.  Therefore, this expression is valid.

## Standard reference

For non-overloaded `operator=` (i.e., for `int`): [[expr.ass]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ass#1)

> The assignment operator (`=`) and the compound assignment operators
>   all group right-to-left. All require **a modifiable lvalue as their
>   left operand** and return an lvalue referring to the left operand. 
>   [...]

For overload `operator=` (for `std::string`): [[expr.ass]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ass#4)

> If the left operand is of class type, the class shall be complete.
>   **Assignment to objects of a class is defined by the copy/move assignment operator** ([class.copy], [over.ass]).

(emphasis mine for all)

Comment: It gets weirder in that the assignment returns an lvalue, not an xvalue.

Comment: @DavisHerring Yes.  I'd say that `std::string` wasn't designed for rvalue assignment in the first place, so it doesn't bother propagating value category.

Comment: @L.F. it's all the std containers as far as I can tell

Comment: @RichardCritten: There’s a [paper](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1906r0.pdf) aiming to change that in the core language.

Comment: @DavisHerring Why do you say that assignment return value is `lvalue` and not `xvalue`(or `rvalue`). If it is `lvalue`, it should have identity and associated memory area. What would be identity of return value and where would be its memory?

Comment: @UnSat Thinks of it this way: `category_cast<lvalue>(an_rvalue)` (pseudocode).  It just treats the materialized object of the rvalue as an lvalue.

Comment: @UnSat: …Its identity and storage are that of the temporary materialized to make the xvalue object expression for the (implicit) function call.  But it’s a lot easier to say “It returns `std::string&`, so it’s an lvalue.”.

Comment: @UnSat That's a simplified view on what value categories are. It might be a helpful analogy for some simple scenarios but don't treat it as a definition.

Answer (score 2):

That rule only applies for objects of built-in type, like `int`.

It does not apply for classes.

The rule was probably deemed too restrictive for classes, whose operators can be overloaded to do various things … or perhaps deemed too restrictive all around by the time C++ came about, but it wouldn't have been alright to break old C code by relaxing the rule for built-ins too.

Regardless, the result of your addition is actually an lvalue, because that's what you get when you return an lvalue reference like `std::string&` from a function. That's despite the fact that both operands of the addition were rvalue expressions and temporary objects. It's perhaps a bit surprising here, and [there's a proposal to do better at "propagating value category"](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1906r0.pdf) in such cases, now that the language gives us the tools to do so.

Comment: The result of addition (the `+` expression which is an `operator+` call) is an rvalue. The result of assignment is an lvalue.

Comment: @aschepler Hmm [guess you're right](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b388e67f3f05d22). I never thought the rules for built-in ops would apply to the overloaded ones. Indeed, I'm sure there was a case recently where one such rule clearly did not. I smell inconsistency

Comment: It's not using the rule from a built-in operator. The result of adding two strings is an rvalue because the `operator+` function used returns a `std::string` (not a reference).

Comment: @aschepler .... oh yeah.  Why the hell was I thinking of compound assignment? I need a holiday.