# Error in self written code for factorial of a number in c++

Tags: c++

Please point out the error in below code :
     #include 
     using namespace std;

```
 int factorial(int n) {
     int f=1;
     factorial(0)=1;
     factorial(1)=1;
     while(n>=0)
     {
         f=f*factorial(n);
         n=n-1;
     }
     return f;
 }

 int main() {
     cout << factorial(5);
 }
```

In the compiler, I am getting the error "lvalue required as left operand of the assignment factorial(0)=1;"

I am unable to understand the above error. Please explain.

Comment: Your syntax is very wrong. You might want to find a good book, class, or tutorial on C++ (or review the material if you are already doing that).

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? you cannot allocate a value to a function call `factorial(0)=1;`

Comment: What you're trying to do with the `factorial(0)=1;` and `factorial(1)=1;` is written this way: `if (n <= 1) return 1`

Comment: @RomCoo please give the reason behind that

Comment: @kapobajza why can't I write factorial(0)=1 ?

Comment: first tell us what your intention with that line was ;)

Comment: I want to assign the value to factorial function when argument passed is 0 or 1 as equal to 1 then I wanted to calculate the factorial recursively

Comment: Because you cannot assign a function to a value. But you can assign a function to a variable,for example you can do something like `int number = factorial(0);`

Comment: You meant to write `if(n == 0 || n == 1) return 1;`

Comment: Why can't I .. I really want to know the reason.. What's wrong in assigning value to a function?

Comment: Take back your downvotes as my question is genuine

Comment: Assigning a value to a function isn't the way programming languages work. If you want to assign a value,you have to assign it to a variable. A variable is something that's varying/changing(unless you declare it as a constant). So assigning a value to something other than a variable,makes no sense.

Comment: Look at a similar question to my doubt here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216889/if-a-functions-return-an-int-can-an-int-be-assigned-to-it .. At least explain me what's said here. And what is l-value?

Comment: I know what a variable is

Comment: Explain to me clearly why I can't assign value to a function?

Comment: OK u idiots keep downvoting.. This is all u can do as none of u can explain the reason why programming language has done this..

Comment: @RohitSharma _Take back your downvotes as my question is genuine_  It doesn't matter if it is genuine, or not. Hover over downvote button: `This question does not show any research effort`, which it doesn't.

Comment: I hope Bjarn Stroustrup could answer my question

Comment: Fk u algirdas.. I don't care what you all have to say unless you all are able to explain what I am actually asking.. It proves your concepts are weak and none of you are able to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is really wrong. You cannot assign a function to a value. I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Factorial(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;

    return n * Factorial(n - 1);
}

int main()
{
    int number = Factorial(5);
    cout << number << endl;
}
```

Comment: You can't assign value to a function result, because a function itself already _returns_ a value as result, i.e. `int function(int)` _returns_ an `int` as result.

Comment: @Rohit Sharma Really mature to call people morons and idiots when you are the one not understanding the subject matter and the "idiots" are just trying to help you understand. Good luck getting help in the future with that attitude.

Comment: Oh really? And are you really helping me? All that everyone is simply saying is go back to your concepts or language does not allow or blah blah blah.. But no one is focusing on the point why language has done so.. Only user3078414 got close enough to solve my query

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not allow for pattern-matching function definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Update: This one's like school on Saturday...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int& factorial(int n) {
    static std::unordered_map<int,int> memo = {{0,1},{1,1}};
    if(!memo.count(n)) {
        memo[n] = n * factorial(n-1);
    }
    return memo[n];
}

int main() {
    using std::cout;

    cout << factorial(1) << '\n';  
    cout << factorial(5) << '\n';
    cout << "   ----\n";
    factorial(1) = 123456789;      // make factorial(1) better
    cout << factorial(1) << '\n';
    cout << factorial(5) << '\n';  // factorial(5) is still 120
    //                                because its value was saved
    //                                by the first factorial(5) call
}
```

It behaves like the original example, but the memoized results for `factorial(0)` and `factorial(1)` had to be added with an init list, unfortunately.  Starting off with `factorial(0) = 1;` would have caused infinite recursion.  When called with a value `n`, this version also automatically adds any missing factorial values to its memo, for all positive integers <= `n`.  Best of all, the user can still customize the memoized result for any input like this: `factorial(5) = 0;`

Here's an example that uses classes and junk.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

class factorial {
    static std::unordered_map<int,int>& map() {
        static std::unordered_map<int,int> outs;
        return outs;
    }
    int n;
public:
    factorial(int n) : n(n) {}
    factorial& operator = (int out) {
        map()[n] = out;
        return *this;
    }
    operator int () const {
        if(map().count(n)) return map()[n];
        return factorial(n-1) * n;
    }
};

int main() {
    using std::cout;

    // need to set low factorial values
    // to prevent infinite recursion
    factorial(0) = 1;
    factorial(1) = 1;

    cout << factorial(1) << '\n';  
    cout << factorial(5) << '\n';
    cout << "   ----\n";
    factorial(1) = 123456789;      // make factorial(1) better
    cout << factorial(1) << '\n';
    cout << factorial(5) << '\n';  // now factorial(5) is all messed up
    cout << "   ----\n";
    factorial(5) = 120;            // fix factorial(5)
    cout << factorial(5) << '\n';  // worked!
}
```

Output:

```
1
120
   ----
123456789
1929912792
   ----
120
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/LoQQrE)